# Onclick function in js not working properly

Tags: javascript

onclick function to change an image once clicked but its giving me an error in Js saying unexpected else please I need an assistance Im a newbie in programming

```js
function changeImage(){
    let a=document.getElementById("changeimg").src
        if (a==="img/save.png") {
            return a = "img/saveblack.png"
        } 

}  
 else{
    return a= "img/save.png"
}
```

```html
</div>
                
                <div class="wrapper_center">
                    <img src="img/profilepix.jpg">
                </div>

                <div class="wrapper_bottom">
                    <div class="reaction_wrapper">
                        <a href=""><img src="img/heart.png"></a>
                        <a href=""><img src="img/messagereaction.png"></a>
                        <a href=""><img src="img/message.png"></a>
                        <img src="img/save.png" id="changeimg" onclick="changeImage()">
                    </div>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in your example. `"message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'else'",` This is due to your `else` statement existing outside of the `changeImage()` function. Is this the reason it's not working?

Comment: [Edit] question, edit snippet, click "tidy" button on the left, note the indentation.  You have an extra `}` in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

The curly bracket on line 7 should be moved to below the `else` statement. The way it currently is, you're closing the function, and then have an `else` clause not tied with an `if`.

Also, setting `a` to `element.src` will just copy the value of `element.src` to the variable `a`, so if you change `a` at all it won't change `element.src` at all. You can fix this by saving `a` as `element` so that you can modify the properties, since objects (not primitives) are copied by reference and not value.

```js
function changeImage() {
  let a = document.getElementById("changeimg");
 
  if (a.src === "img/save.png") {
    return a.src "img/saveblack.png"
  } else {
    return a.src = "img/save.png"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks  everyone .. another issue is that once clicked the image does not change

Comment: @KELzzz see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this ( I suggest you use a good text editor lik vscode, webstorm, itellij or atom, all the syntax errors you have will be highlighted)

```js
function changeImage(){
    let element = document.getElementById("changeimg")
    element.src = element.src ==="img/save.png" ? "img/saveblack.png" : "img/save.png";
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper_center">
<img src="img/profilepix.jpg">
</div> 
<div class="wrapper_bottom"> 
 <div class="reaction_wrapper"> 
   <a href="">
    <img src="img/heart.png">
   </a> 
   <a href=""><img src="img/messagereaction.png"></a> 
   <a href=""><img src="img/message.png"></a>
   <img src="img/save.png" id="changeimg" onclick="changeImage()">  </div>
</div>
```